# Remove apostrophe from parameter query in MVC?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, security

I realize that this topic has been discussed heavily... I have read a lot of posts about SQL injection etc. I apologize if I am asking a similar question, but I have not been able to find an answer to my situation.

I have a field on a search page that allows the user to search based on title. My project builds a SQL query string to retrieve the data but the string is never a part of the URL. In the event that someone searches for a title that has an apostrophe in it, the query fails. I want to know how to fix this and what other safe guards I need to be secure while allowing users to search based on title. Please note that ultimately there will be about 20,000 titles to choose from.

In POST of my Controller: (Along with about 50 other parameters)

```
 if (results.Title != null)
                wherestatements.Add("title like '%" +  results.Title + "%'");
 //Collect all other values of the search//

 //BUILD SQL statement//
 SQLstatement = string.Format("select * from Cards where {0} and {1} and (({2}) or ({3})) 
 and CardID In (Select CardID from CardAbilities where {4});",
 final, //This is my where the title is included
 finalexcludefrommulti, finalsplit, finalmulti, finalability);

 //EXECUTE Query & Return View//
 var CardList = db.Cards.SqlQuery(SQLstatement).ToList();
  return View(CardList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
```

Comment: You're *definitely* going to want to get rid of that SQL injection vulnerability.  That's the root cause of your problem, and can become the root cause of much, much worse problems.  It's not really clear from the SQL query posted what its actual structure is, since it's built from variables we don't see.  But essentially you want to use query parameters instead of directly executing user input as code.  This can get a little tricky with dynamically adding checks to the `WHERE` clause, but not impossible.

Comment: Do not ever build a complete sql statement from user input.  If you've done the appropriate research, then you should be completely aware the only safe way to pass user input is through parameters.

Comment: I am all for getting rid of the vulnerability. I just don't know how to use query parameters and I am not sure how to get it to work with the where statements. How would using parameters still allow someone to search a title that includes an apostrophe without letting SQL injection apostrophes get through?

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I have made it so that only letters can be accepted as input with the exception of an apostrophe which is then substituted before being passed to the query. I would still like to know how to do this with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Better approach will be to use ORM and query the lists/ filter it as you want it. 
I agree with other never ever expose your website with sql injections.

Comment: Given the SQL string with variables above, here is an example what that can turn into as a SQL statement. I will have to break this up into multiple comments due to the character limitation: `select * from Cards where power > 3 and toughness <= 5 and maintypeid = 1 and subtypeid = 15 and rarityid = 1 and greenbluemanacost is null  and greenblackmanacost is null  and blueblackmanacost is null  and greenmanacost is null  and bluemanacost is null  and blackmanacost is null  and ((redwhitemanacost > 0  or redgreenmanacost > 0 or redbluemanacost > 0  or redblackmanacost > 0  or redorlifecost > 0`

Comment: `or whitegreenmanacost > 0  or redwhitemanacost > 0 or whitebluemanacost > 0  or whiteblackmanacost > 0  or whiteorlifecost > 0 ) or (redmanacost > 0  or whitemanacost > 0 )) and CardID In (Select CardID from CardAbilities where abilityid = 2) and CardSetID In(Select distinct CardSetID from Cardsets where cardsets.ReleaseDate= (Select Max(ReleaseDate) from CardSets));` How do I create that query from user input safely?

Answer (score -1):

Well I would say change to use parameters instead of injecting value into your SQL but since your `WHERE` clause is pretty dynamic it will not be simple.  Seems like you need to:

1) Generate a collection of WHERE clauses, each of which contains a reference to a parameter
2) Add the parameter value to a list of values

so something like:

```
List<object> parameters = new List<object>();

...


if (results.Title != null)
{
    wherestatements.Add("title like @title");
    parameters.Add("%" + results.Title + "%");
}
//Collect all other values of the search//

//BUILD SQL statement//
SQLstatement = string.Format("select * from Cards where {0} and {1} and (({2}) or ({3})) and CardID In (Select CardID from CardAbilities where {4});",
final, //This is my where the title is included
finalexcludefrommulti, finalsplit, finalmulti, finalability);
```

then execute your query by passing in parameters:

```
//EXECUTE Query & Return View//
var CardList = db.Cards.SqlQuery(SQLstatement, parameters).ToList();
                                               ^-- pass parameters here
```

Comment: How does this prevent `{0}` from being `-- Drop Table Users` (sql injection)?

Comment: @ErikPhilips It depends on how the value that gets injected is generated.  If it's user input then there is still a vulnerability.  However if it's generated by code as the question would suggest (`"title like @title"`) then SQL injection is not possible.